# ZFTool generates wrong paths to class files

Tags: php, code-generation, zend-framework2

I installed the ZFTool (`/usr/bin/zf2` references `/lib/ZendFramework/ZFTool/zf.php`)

```
user@machine:/var/www/.../projectroot/module/Catalo# zf2 version
ZFTool - Zend Framework 2 command line Tool ver. 0.1
The ZFTool is using Zend Framework 2.1.3
```

and it's working fine. But when I try to generate a classmap

```
user@machine:/var/www/.../projectroot/module/Catalo# zf2 classmap generate . -w
```

it creates a classmap with wrong paths:

```
<?php
// Generated by Zend Framework 2
return array(
    'Catalog\Module'                       => __DIR__ . '/../../../../../../.././Module.php',
    'Catalog\Controller\CatalogController' => __DIR__ . '/../../../../../../.././src/Catalog/Controller/CatalogController.php',
);
```

Why? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Why not just use the classmap generator util that ships with the framework? http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.loader.classmap-generator.html

Comment: Thank you, it has worked! Bu why is the [ZFTool Classmap generator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html#classmap-generator) generating the wrong paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in ZFTool. I deployed a fix that you can see at https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool/pull/28.

Basically, ZFTool was failing to compare the directory to be crawled and the target classmap file directory. This turned out into producing the fancy output you were experiencing.

***EDIT***: merged - the fix is already in ZFTool

Comment: I've just downloaded the current [ZFTool Phar](http://packages.zendframework.com/zftool.phar) and tried it out again. The paths are still wrong.

Comment: Ack... guess the PHAR is not yet updated. You probably need to build it on your own with the `bin/create-phar` command ( https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool/blob/master/bin/create-phar )

Comment: The generated paths contain double slashes like `'Catalog\Module' => __DIR__ . '//Module.php',` This doesn't causes any errors, the script works fine. But maybe it should also be corrected.

Comment: @automatix you should probably report that on the `ZFTool` issue tracker

Comment: [done](https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool/issues/29)